# Example of simple validation in appsync with cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, serverless, aws-appsync

I'm just beginning to look into appsync and cognito, and theres a lot of good examples around, but i can't find one that shows how to limit a user's ability to mutate data based on identity.

Here is what i speculate would be an easy example:

- "cat" item has: name, desctiption, and creator_id
- all users can create "cat" items
- they do not specify the owner_id
- it is inferred from their identity in cognito
- users can edit cat items that have a matching creator_id

I'm assuming this is a really dumb lambda script - but I haven't been able to find any examples that cover this.

Thanks for your help,

-Michael

Answer (score 4):

Someone on reddit shared this link, which seems like exactly what i'm looking for:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security.html